# What is a good default value for setting timeout conditionally?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, settimeout

`setTimeout` returns a number, a timeoutId, which is used by `clearTimeout` to identify and remove it.

However, what value do I use if I want to set the timeout conditionally? Is 0 a safe ID to use?

It's used in a React context where clearing the timeout is generally considered good practice.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = success ? setTimeout(() => foo(), 300) : defaultVal;

  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, [success]);
```

Or is it perhaps better to wrap the entire thing in one big condition and avoid the default value altogether?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (success) 
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => foo(), 300);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
}, [success]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 0 is a safe value to use because it will [never be returned](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps) by `setTimeout`:

> ... let *id* be an implementation-defined integer that is greater than zero ...

And it's [not an error](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-cleartimeout) to pass 0 to `clearTimeout`:

> The `clearTimeout(id)` [...] method steps are to remove this's map of active timers[*id*].
>
> ...
>
> To remove an entry from an ordered map is to remove all entries from the map that match a given condition, or do nothing if none do.

But even though it's safe and supported, I normally use `null` for this case. That means I need to check for a non-`null` value before calling `clearTimeout`, but it makes the intent of the code clearer.

Comment: I skimmed the spec but couldn't find the section about the ID not being zero, so I thought it safer to ask :)